# Googlebot not recognizing dynamic robots.txt

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, robots.txt, googlebot

I have created a dynamic route with laravel that serves a txt response.

It works on the browser, but googlebot says that there is no `robots.txt` file.

This is the header that I get:

`Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Disposition →inline; filename="robots.txt"
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 23 Mar 2016 11:36:44 GMT
Server →nginx/1.9.12
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding`

This is my my laravel route:

`Route::get('robots.txt', 'TxtController@robots');`

And this is the method:

`public function robots(){
    return response()->view('txt.robots')->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="robots.txt"');
}`

I tried with `Content-Disposition →attachment; filename="robots.txt"` but google keeps saying that there is no `robots.txt` file.

I have tried to delete the `Content-Disposition` and stills not work from Google Web Master Tools (It works on the browser)

This is my **nginx configuration**, maybe there is something wrong here:

```

````
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name mydomain.com;
root /home/forge/mydomain.com/public;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
# ssl_certificate;
# ssl_certificate_key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;



location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
#location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

#location = /robots.txt {
#    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#    access_log off;
#    log_not_found off;
#}

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}


# Expire rules for static content

# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
    expires -1;
    # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
}

# Feed
location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
    expires 1h;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS, Javascript and Fonts
location ~* \.(?:css|js|woff|ttf|eot)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
}
```
````

Thank you.

Comment: Try to remove 'Content-Disposition', 'inline; from the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding a Content-length header. The code result is this one:

```
    $response = response()->view('txt.robots')->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    $response->header('Content-Length',strlen($response->getOriginalContent()));

    return $response;
```

I hope this helps. thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

When I inspect http://www.google.com/robots.txt the HTTP response headers are:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1574
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Wed, 23 Mar 2016 12:07:44 GMT
Expires:Wed, 23 Mar 2016 12:07:44 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 04 Mar 2016 19:02:51 GMT
Server:sffe
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Why not skip the `Content-Disposition` header and just output text with a `Content-Type:text/plain` header?

Also...

- Are you sure your robots.txt url is available from the outside world? Maybe use a proxy to double check.
- Is your output UTF-8 encoded?

See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt for more info

Comment: I added the Content-Disposition while trying to make it work. My original code had just one header (text/plain)

You can access /robots.txt from outside without problems and it's supposed to be utf-8, because of the header `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Disposition` header is used to force file download in browser. It probably confuses Google bot - try giving the file without it:

```
public function robots(){
    return response()->view('txt.robots')->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
}
```

Comment: This is my original code, but i t doesn't work for google. The response is correct, but google webmaster tools says that there is no `robots.txt` file

Comment: Is it accessible for you from browser? Also `robots.txt` content matters - you must enable access to the file itself

Comment: Yes, you can access with the browser and I have validated its content.
The problem is that is not a static file, is a server response with a text/plain header. I have checked my nginx configuration and it works too.